# quarter year wise filteration in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table having structure as follows

```
id cust_id target month year fiscal_ID
1  234     50     4     2013 1 
2  234     50     5     2013 1
3  234     50     6     2013 1
4  234     150    7     2013 1
5  234     150    8     2013 1
6  234     150    9     2013 1
```

I need to get the result as follows

```
cust_id target quarter year fiscal_ID
234     150    Q1      2013 1
234     450    Q2      2013 1
```

months 4,5,6 in Q1, 7,8,9 in Q2 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are storing the `month` and `year` in separate columns, one way you can get the result is to use a derived table that references the month and quarter and you join to that data:

```
select t.cust_id,
  sum(target) target,
  d.qtr,
  t.year,
  t.fiscal_id
from yourtable t
inner join
(
  select 4 mth, 'Q1' qtr union all
  select 5 mth, 'Q1' qtr union all
  select 6 mth, 'Q1' qtr union all
  select 7 mth, 'Q2' qtr union all
  select 8 mth, 'Q2' qtr union all
  select 9 mth, 'Q2' 
) d
  on t.month = d.mth
group by t.cust_id, d.qtr, t.year, t.fiscal_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/139b8/2).

Comment: Sir what should i do if i need it as :                              cust_id target    quarter year fiscal_ID
234     150/450   Q1/Q2   2013 1

Comment: @PhilipSams Please post a new question with the updated requirements.

Comment: @PhilipSams No, don't edit this question post a new question with the new requirements.

Comment: here is the url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279943/quarter-year-wise-result-filteration-in-sql